# Add deeplink shortcut to YouTube playlist

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

My Dad is in a nursing home and I'm trying to make his days a bit more interesting. He's unable to do much more than sit still so operating technology is out of the question. The carers are too busy and generally not interested in technology. So I need a **really** simple solution to play some Youtube content.

I've put a Nexus7 tablet in the room which is running Lollipop with the stock Google launcher and a Chromecast in the TV. I've removed all icons from the homescreen except the YouTube one so the carers don't accidently get lost. I've created a Youtube playlist that would brighten up his days (old comedy FTW!). However, to get to the playlist the carer needs to tap the user icon and then scroll down to the correct one (possibly too much).

I'd like to make it even simpler so that a deep link to the actual playlist appears on the homescreen.

I'm happy to try anything (custom widget, launcher, 3rd party app etc) but after a lot of searching I haven't been able to find anything that is as simple for the user as I need. Does anyone know how I might be able to achieve this on Lollipop?

Comment: I don't use YouTube app but I think [QuickShortcutMaker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sika524.android.quickshortcut) *may be* able to help you out. Try it to create (YouTube) shortcuts which a launcher normally doesn't allow.